# Use train_test_split to output into dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn

So I thought I was smart (turns out I am not), I would like to to use the `train_test_split` function to output its data directly into a dictionary that I created beforehand.

```
{"train":{"x":None, "y":None},
 "val":{"x":None, "y":None},
 "test":{"x":None, "y":None}}
```

I would like to feed into each `"x"` and `"y"` the relevant data using the aforementioned split function.  However, when I do this all `"x"` entries in the dictionary receive the same data. So `datasets["train"]["x"]` will have the same values as `datasets["test"]["x"]`. You can see that this true by using the example below.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(200,10)
y = np.random.rand(200)

splits =  [0.8,0.1,0.1]
sets = ["train","val", "test"]
datasets = dict(zip(sets[:len(splits)], [{"x":None, "y":None}]*len(splits) ))

datasets["train"]["x"],_,_,_  = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=42)
print(datasets["train"]["x].shape[0],datasets["test"]["x"].shape[0])
```

I guess my approach does not work. So I would like to know why, for learning reasons. And also how to achieve the thing that I was set out to achieve.

```
datasets["train"]["x"],datasets["val"]["x"],datasets["train"]["y"],datasets["val"]["y"]  = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=42)
print(datasets["train"]["x].shape[0],datasets["test"]["x"].shape[0])
```

This should (in my midn result into `datasets["test"]["x"] still being` None`

Answer (score 1):

works in my hands:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
x = np.random.rand(200,10)
y = np.random.rand(200)

q = {'a': {'a':None, 'b': None}, 'b': {'a':None, 'b': None}}
q['a']['a'], q['a']['b'], q['b']['a'], q['b']['b'] = train_test_split(x, y, train_size=0.8, random_state=42)
```

Comment: haha fuck me yes it does.
Actually the way I create the origanll dictionary causes the issue
splits =[0.8,0.1,0.1] 
datasets = dict(zip(sets[:len(splits)], [{"x":None, "y":None}]*len(splits) ))

Comment: So below you can find the reason for the error I experienced.

Answer (score 1):

The issue stems from how I initialize my Dictionary

```
splits = [0.8,0.1,0.1]
datasets = dict(zip(sets[:len(splits)], [{"x":None, "y":None}]*len(splits) ))
```

will result in the above mentioned error.
To fix this you can just generate the dictionary with:

```
splits = [0.8,0.1,0.1]
datasets = {sets[i]:{"x": None, "y":None} for i in range(len(splits) )}
```

I assume maybe the first way leads to some shared memory. But I am too much of a CS Noob that I would not trust my thinking on that.